# Is it possible to mock DB connection in play functional testing and how?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework, mocking, implicit

Some of my controllers rely on DB connection and structured as follows:

```
def getAll(revId: Muid) = Action { implicit request =>
        DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
...
```

I am trying to create a unit test for it with all mocked dependencies, including the connection as well. Now, injection of dependencies is easily done through Guice. However, I am struggling to find a way to mock implicit connection. And, eventually, the test is trying to connect to my default DB in test.

Is it even possible to mock implicits, given this situation, and how?

**UPDATE**

So, after playing with this thing for a while, I got the following:
My class under test:

```
class ChecklistCreationScheduler @Inject()(jobScheduler: JobScheduler,
                                           dBApi: DBApi,
                                           futureChecklistRepository: FutureChecklistRepository) extends ClassLogger{
def scheduleSingleFutureChecklistJob(futureChecklistId: Muid): Unit = {
    logger.info(s"Preparing to schedule one time future checklist job for future checklist id '${futureChecklistId.uuid}'")
    val db = dBApi.database("default")
    logger.info("Database" + db)
    db.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      logger.info("Connection" + connection)
      ...
    }
}
}
```

And the test:

```
"ChecklistCreationScheduler#scheduleSingleFutureChecklistJob" should {
      "schedule a single job through a scheduler" in {
        val futureChecklistId = Muid.random()

        val jobScheduler = mock[JobScheduler]

        val connection = mock[Connection]
        val DB = mock[Database]
        DB.getConnection returns connection

        val dbApi = mock[DBApi]
        when(dbApi.database("default")).thenReturn(DB)

        val futureChecklistRepository = mock[FutureChecklistRepository]
        doReturn(Option.empty).when(futureChecklistRepository).getById(futureChecklistId)(connection)

        val chCreationScheduler = new ChecklistCreationScheduler(jobScheduler, dbApi, futureChecklistRepository)

        chCreationScheduler.scheduleSingleFutureChecklistJob(futureChecklistId) must throwA[UnexpectedException]
      }
    }
```

When I execute the test, it seems like the execution does not even get into the block of `withConnection`. (I am never getting to this line: `logger.info("Connection" + connection)`).

Any idea?

Comment: You can have a look at [Acolyte](http://acolyte.eu.org/)

Comment: Do you really need to mock the connection or you need to mock what is returned by that `withConnection` call? Also, do you really need this to be a unit test?

Comment: Well, all I want is to be able to inject my own mocked 'implicit connection'. As for unit test, I am trying to avoid full integration testing.

Comment: That would be tricky. The only way to mock the connection would be mocking the [`getConnection`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-jdbc/src/main/scala/play/api/db/Databases.scala#L142-L159) method itself. Can you instead inject a [`Database`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.db.Database) instead of the `DB` object? That would make things a way more simple.

Comment: _"Can you instead inject a Database instead of the DB object"_ <- that was exactly my question. And also, is `getConnection` is actually used in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can use [Dependency Injection](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection) to easily mock the database call:

Considering this is your controller:

```
package controllers

import javax.inject.Inject

import play.api._
import play.api.db.Database
import play.api.mvc._

class Application @Inject() (database: Database) extends Controller {

  def index = Action { implicit request =>
    database.withConnection { implicit  connection =>
      ???
    }
    Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
  }
}
```

You can write a [Specification like this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaTestingWithSpecs2):

```
import java.sql.Connection

import controllers.Application
import org.specs2.mutable._
import org.specs2.runner._
import org.junit.runner._
import org.specs2.mock._
import play.api.db.Database
import play.api.mvc.RequestHeader

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class ApplicationSpec extends Specification with Mockito {

  "Application" should {

    "index page" in {
      val connection = mock[Connection]
      val database = mock[Database]
      database.getConnection returns connection

      val controller = new Application(database)

      // You will also need to mock the request
      // so that you can add the expected behavior 
      val request = mock[RequestHeader]
      val result = controller.index(request)

      // do some assert about your result
      result must not beNull
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, some other mocks may be necessary to handle your (whole) use case.

Comment: So, apparently, this does not really work. When I am trying to do it, the execution does not even go into the closure block. Updating my post to show that.